# Line opacity different from Shape opacity plotly dash

Tags: plotly

So I'm adding some squares to a figure, that have an opacity value based on how often they occur. However, I would like a line around the shape that with an opacity of 1, but I cannot seem to set the opacity in the line (dict) property.

```
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
              xref="x", yref="y",
              x0=0, y0=0,
              x1=(img_width_half_pitch/3) * scale_factor, y1=img_height_half_pitch * scale_factor,
              line=dict(
                  color="white",
                  width=3,
                  opacity=1
              ),
              fillcolor="Red",
              opacity=alpha_left
              )
```

Any idea how to get the lines with 1 opacity. I know I could probably make another shape with only a line but that seems very redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are five different ways to specify colors in plotly, among which the rgba format allows you to set alpha values. For example, green with an alpha value of 1.0 is `rgba(0,128,0,1.0)`. Since there was no data provided in the question, I created a graph with appropriate values and attached the image.

> The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as:
> - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
> - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
> - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
> - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
> - A named CSS color:
> aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,...

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

img_width_half_pitch = 90
img_height_half_pitch = 90
scale_factor = 100
alpha_left=0.75
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_shape(type="rect",
              xref="x", yref="y",
              x0=0, y0=0,
              x1=(img_width_half_pitch/3) * scale_factor,
              y1=img_height_half_pitch * scale_factor,
              line=dict(
                  color="rgba(0,128,0,1.0)",
                  width=5,
                  #opacity=1
              ),
              fillcolor="Red",
              opacity=alpha_left
              )
fig.show()
```

[image]